# Cancel UIScrollView scrolling

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad

Is there a way I can cancel scrolling in 'scrollViewWillBeginDragging' based on certain conditions?

Answer (score 1):

`scrollViewWillBeginDragging` is merely a courtesy delegate method. Note the return type is `void`, which means this is not a "shouldXYZ" delegate method with a `BOOL` return type to control behaviour. It's just telling you "FYI, dragging is about to happen".

You will probably have to manually set the `scrollEnabled` property in your `UIScrollView` as desired to turn on and off scrolling altogether.

Comment: Setting scrollEnabled to false and then to true worked perfectly. Thanks a lot.